# Dynamically changing bean scope during JUnit testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, javabeans

During JUnit testing I'd like to test my bean from multiple threads as `singleton` and `prototype`.

I'm using this construct:

```
    // to test singleton
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    registry.getBeanDefinition("myBean").setScope("singleton");

    // it's called from separate thread
    MyBean myBean = applicationContext.getBean("myBean");
```

Now for prototype

```
    // to test prototype
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    registry.getBeanDefinition("myBean").setScope("prototype");

    // it's called from separate thread
    MyBean myBean = applicationContext.getBean("myBean");
```

But it seems it has no effect and bean scope defined in `applicationContext.xml` is used.

How to dynamically change bean's scope without any tricks with multiple `applicationContext`s?

Comment: I think it is impossible to change the scope of a bean after it is created.

Comment: I'm creating bean LATER (at least I'm requesting bean later)

Comment: Are you sure that the bean is really created later? -- Have you tested this statement?

Comment: Well, actually you're right. Regardless to scope defined in `applicationContext` bean is created BEFORE scope is dynamically set. However, if `applicationContext` states `prototype` scope, beans are also created after that. Anyway, think you got what I need. How I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done this that way:

```
    // to test singleton
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry)applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    // registry.getBeanDefinition("myBean").setScope("prototype"); <-- removed this
    BeanDefinition def = registry.getBeanDefinition("myBean");
    def.setScope("prototype"); // or `singleton`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    registry.registerBeanDefinition("myBean", def);

    // it's called from separate thread
    MyBean myBean = applicationContext.getBean("myBean");
```

Just re-registering bean definition in registry does the trick.